# CSS classes under a class

Tags: css

This question may be foolish, though I want to know from experts in CSS. Is there a way to write CSS classes under one class.

Suppose I have a few divs under a div

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="c1"></div>
     <div class="c2"></div>
     <div class="c3"></div>
</div>
```

Normally, we write css classes like below-

```
.parent { width: 100%; }
.parent .c1 { //somecode }
.parent .c2 { //somecode }
.parent .c3 { //somecode }
```

But, I want to know. Can we write like below-

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
   .c1 {
      //somecode
   }
   .c2 {
      //somecode
   }
   .c3 {
      //somecode
   }
}
```

Please let me know the answer on my curiosity. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't using normal css.

Maybe you are looking for [less](http://lesscss.org/)? Specifically the Nested Rules section further down the page.

This allows you to do what you are asking, along with many other useful functions, variables and mixins.

Alternatively there is the option of [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Which is very similar to less.

Comment: I believe it would be more helpfull to describe css pre-processors instead of a specific approach of them – let the user decide for himself.

Answer (score 0):

CSS can't do that, but [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) can.

Take note these are CSS compilers, so they'll need a compile step and *generate* the needed CSS for you (instead of you writing everything by hand).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for something similar to nesting or selector Inheritance.

This can be done with SASS. Very similar to LESS. http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 0):

no you cant using normal css, but for readability purposes, and if you aren't going to use .c1-3 in anything other than a parent class then you could just indent your CSS and do

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
}
   .c1 {
      //somecode
   }
   .c2 {
      //somecode
   }
   .c3 {
      //somecode
   }
```

in this way you can easily see in your code which classes belong to which parent classes. (if you don't want to go down the LESS SASS route

Comment: .c1 wont be scoped to the .parent element however.

Comment: no it won't but if you arent going to use .c1-3 in anything other than .parent, and don't want to use a pre-processor, indenting your code will make it more readable.